# Core Data inheritance and relationship

Tags: iphone, inheritance, core-data, entity-relationship

I have a following data model:

Entity User, which inherits from entity Contact.

Contact has one-to-one relationship with an entity ContactInfo.

User has one-to-many relationship to Contact.

ContactInfo has a reverse relationship to Contact and Contact in its turn has a reverse relationship to User.

I'm creating a ContactInfo object for User:

```
        ContactInfo *moInfo = [self createContactInfoManagedObject];
        moInfo.contact = userMO;
        userMO.contactInfo = moInfo;
```

where createContactInfoManagedObject returns an object of type ContactInfo.
I'm getting following exception on the line

```
        moInfo.contact = userMO;


Unacceptable type of value for to-one relationship: property = "contact"; desired type = Contact; given type = NSManagedObject; value = <NSManagedObject: 0x3b2850> (entity: User; id: 0x3d4fa0 <x-coredata://4889CBE0-094B-49DB-B525-C87F7CD1AA68/User/p1> ; data: {
    contacts =     (
        "0x3d4fa0 <x-coredata://4889CBE0-094B-49DB-B525-C87F7CD1AA68/User/p1>"
    );
    user = "0x3d4fa0 <x-coredata://4889CBE0-094B-49DB-B525-C87F7CD1AA68/User/p1>";
    contactInfo = "0x3ebdc0 <x-coredata:///VCard/t128311BC-4B82-45CF-B87C-9AD38CBC89163>";
}).
```

My question is what's wrong here?
I think something 's wrong with inheritance when I try to assign User entity to a contact relationship. Please advise!
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `userMO` object coming from?

The error message suggests it is an instance of `NSManagedObject`, but it is expecting an instance of `Contact`.

Comment: The error talks about `property = "contact"` problem, that it's being assigned an NSManagedObject, while it expects Contact object, but User derives from Contact so I cannot understand where the error comes from.

Comment: Are you sure you set the managed object class for the Contact entity to the Contact class in your object model?  In any case, @paulbailey is right -- we need to see how you create the `userMO` object.

Answer (score 0):

try to cast the object:

```
 ContactInfo *moInfo =(ContactInfo*) [self createContactInfoManagedObject];
```

Comment: createContactInfoManagedObject returns a ContactInfo object, casting will not change much